# Incompatible Comparison Error from Filter Length

Tags: python, sql-server, django, django-pyodbc

## Question

I am getting an incompatible comparison error detailed below, but it's dependent on the size of the string I'm passing to the filter. Anyone know what the cause of or solution to this error would be, or where I can dig in deeper to identify the root-issue?

## Details

When I query filtering with a string of length 255 I receive a `False` response as I expected (doesn't quite match my inserted column value):

```
>>> from core.models import TestTable
>>> test_str = '--publication_filter|920,921,922,923,925,926,927,928,929,930,932,933,934,935,936,937,938,939,940,941,1024,1237,1239,1255,1302,1386,1442,1724,1842,9926,9929,9979,12818,12822,12864,12867,21301,21417,21418,21419,21420,21570,22046,22080,22081,22087,22167,1234'
>>> len(test_str)
255
>>> test1 = TestTable.objects.filter(test_column=test_str)
>>> test1.exists()
False
```

However, with a string of length 256 which I expect return `True` (matches my inserted column value), it instead raises an error (this test is exactly the same as the one above except `test_str` is one character longer):

**Note:** I've redacted my path in the traceback below.

```
>>> from core.models import TestTable
>>> test_str = '--publication_filter|920,921,922,923,925,926,927,928,929,930,932,933,934,935,936,937,938,939,940,941,1024,1237,1239,1255,1302,1386,1442,1724,1842,9926,9929,9979,12818,12822,12864,12867,21301,21417,21418,21419,21420,21570,22046,22080,22081,22087,22167,12345'
>>> len(test_str)
256
>>> test2 = TestTable.objects.filter(test_column=test_str)
>>> test2.exists()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/[REDACTED]/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 565, in exists
    return self.query.has_results(using=self.db)
  File "/[REDACTED]/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 441, in has_results
    return bool(compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE))
  File "/[REDACTED]/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 818, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/[REDACTED]/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sql_server/pyodbc/base.py", line 325, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]The data types nvarchar and text are incompatible in the equal to operator. (402) (SQLParamData)')
```

Looking at and running the raw query works fine, which has me very suspicious of the `django-pyodbc` package I'm on.

```
>>> str(TestTable.objects.filter(test_column=test_str).query)
'SELECT [custom].[test_table].[test_id], [custom].[test_table].[test_column] FROM [custom].[test_table] WHERE [custom].[test_table].[test_column] = --publication_filter|920,921,922,923,925,926,927,928,929,930,932,933,934,935,936,937,938,939,940,941,1024,1237,1239,1255,1302,1386,1442,1724,1842,9926,9929,9979,12818,12822,12864,12867,21301,21417,21418,21419,21420,21570,22046,22080,22081,22087,22167,12345 '
```

Edited query (quotes fixed), returns without issues manually querying my DB:

```
SELECT [custom].[test_table].[test_id], [custom].[test_table].[test_column]
FROM [custom].[test_table]
WHERE [custom].[test_table].[test_column] = '--publication_filter|920,921,922,923,925,926,927,928,929,930,932,933,934,935,936,937,938,939,940,941,1024,1237,1239,1255,1302,1386,1442,1724,1842,9926,9929,9979,12818,12822,12864,12867,21301,21417,21418,21419,21420,21570,22046,22080,22081,22087,22167,12345'
```

## Additional Information

### System

- **Server OS:** Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
- **DB Driver:** FreeTDS
- **`djanbo-pyodbc` package:** https://github.com/avidal/django-pyodbc/tree/django-1.4

  - **Note:** For some unknown reason, we build our project off of a locally stored copy of this package, but this is the branch of the package I believe we're on.

### Table

```
CREATE TABLE [custom].[test_table] (
    test_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
    test_column NVARCHAR(4000),
);

INSERT INTO custom.test_table (test_column)
VALUES ('--publication_filter|920,921,922,923,925,926,927,928,929,930,932,933,934,935,936,937,938,939,940,941,1024,1237,1239,1255,1302,1386,1442,1724,1842,9926,9929,9979,12818,12822,12864,12867,21301,21417,21418,21419,21420,21570,22046,22080,22081,22087,22167,12345');
```

### Model

```
class TestTable(models.Model):
    test_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    test_column = models.TextField(null=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'custom].[test_table'
```

Comment: So this may be an example where the package you're using `django-pyodbc` isn't behaving as intended for some reason or another. You can debug the actual raw SQL query itself by attaching `.query` to the end of a statement. So for you it would look like `TestTable.objects.filter(test_column=test_str).exists().query`.

Comment: It would also help if you included a link to the `django-pyodbc` package you're using (there are several forks), which OS you're connecting from, and your driver stack (MS ODBC? FreeTDS?).

Comment: @raiderrobert

That doesn't work as you've written it, raises `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. Should be `TestTable.objects.filter(test_column=test_str).query`.

Running the raw query doesn't give me any issues, which has me suspicious of my `django-pyodbc` package as you've mentioned. I've updated my question with this info.

Thank you. Haven't been able to dive in further yet due to other obligations.

Comment: @FlipperPA

I've updated my question with this info: **Server OS:** Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS, **DB Driver:** FreeTDS, **`djanbo-pyodbc` package:** https://github.com/avidal/django-pyodbc/tree/django-1.4 (Note: For some unknown reason, we build our project off of a locally stored copy of this package, but this is the branch of the package I believe we're on.)

Thank you. I'm very suspicious my `django-pyodbc` package is likely the issue at this point (I can run the raw query without issue), but I haven't been able to dive in further yet due to other obligations.

Comment: @lengeta, sorry about that bug in my code. I should have remembered that `.exists()` returns a `bool` and not a `queryset` object. Simple question. Could you try doing a `.count()`or a `.first()` on the end for some more debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several `django-pyodbc` flavors out there, but out of the packages I've tried, `django-pyodbc-azure` has performed best. I would recommend giving it a shot:

https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure

Comment: I haven't been able to jump back to this issue, and won't be able to any time soon. I also don't want to leave this question open forever either, so I've gone ahead and selected this as the correct answer. I'm not 100% certain my issue lies with my `django-pyodbc` package, but I'm fairly confident it will turn our to be my issue here.